# How to force angular while executing take files from /dist folder (now webpack takes them from it's memory)

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, nyc, angular-builder

The problem is that we have to test code coverage in our angular project. So we use nyc, nyc modified source files(and insert some code to collect code coverage), but the issue is that while serving application webpack takes files from memory, not from /dist folder and these files are without our changes from nyc.

in summary what we are doing:

1. we are builing project and get files in /dist folder
2. we run some scripts and modify our source files in /dist folder.
3. we run application and dont see our changes, because webpack takes source files from it's own memory not from /dist folder.

the question is: how to run angular and force it to take files from /dist

Comment: Why don't you use a built-in coverage reporter (`ng test --code-coverage`)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.